# Error al tratar de leer los correos de gmail desde c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy tratando de leer los correos de la bandeja de entrada de google, la cuestión es que cuando trato de ejecutar el codigo genera un error en esta linea

```
using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
```

El error generado es el siguiente:

```
{"Error en la inicialización del sistema de configuración"}
```

El codigo que estoy utilizando para realizar la lectura lo e obtenido desde Internet el cual es el siguiente:

```
public List<Message> getMensajes()
    {
        try
        {

            // El cliente se desconecta al terminar el using
            using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
            {
                // conectamos al servidor
                client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);

                // Autentificación
                client.Authenticate(username, password);

                // Obtenemos los Uids mensajes
                List<string> uids = client.GetMessageUids();

                // creamos instancia de mensajes
                List<Message> lstMessages = new List<Message>();

                // Recorremos para comparar
                for (int i = 0; i < uids.Count; i++)
                {
                    //obtenemos el uid actual, es él id del mensaje
                    string currentUidOnServer = uids[i];

                    //por medio del uid obtenemos el mensaje con el siguiente metodo
                    Message oMessage = client.GetMessage(i + 1);

                    //agregamos el mensaje a la lista que regresa el metodo
                    lstMessages.Add(oMessage);

                }

                // regresamos la lista
                return lstMessages;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //si ocurre una excepción regresamos null, es importante que cachen las excepciones, yo
            //lo hice general por modo de ejemplo
            MensError = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Los permisos de la cuenta de google esta habilitados para aplicación poco seguras y se le ha dado los acceso para pop3 desde la configuración, ya que se tiene un aplicativo en java que si puede acceder a la lista de bandeja de entrada, la idea es tratarlo de hacer en c# puesto que se va a aplicar a un proyecto aps.net mvc c#.

Si alguien sabe que esta pasando y como solucionar, se lo agradezco.

**Actualizado**

Al ejecutar la aplicacion, me genera el siguiente error:

> en System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String
>   configKey)    en
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String
>   sectionName)    en
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    en
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    en
>   System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    en
>   System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()    en
>   System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()    en
>   System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_Sources()    en
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()    en
>   System.Net.Logging.InitializeLogging()    en
>   System.Net.Logging.get_On()    en
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(AddressFamily family)    en
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor()    en
>   OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port, Boolean
>   useSsl, Int32 receiveTimeout, Int32 sendTimeout,
>   RemoteCertificateValidationCallback certificateValidator)    en
>   OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port, Boolean
>   useSsl)    en Pruebas.listarEmailGoogle.getMensajes() en
>   E:\GitLab\sistemas\sistemas
>   2\nuevo-sistema-caracterizacion-2.0\SistemaCaracterizacion-2.0\Pruebas\Program.cs:línea
>   272

Comment: Por favor, en vez de `ex.Message`, use `ex.ToString()` y [edit] la pregunta con la excepción completa. Saludos.

Comment: Revisa este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5dPop3), a ver si te ayuda.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave me dice lo mismo que comente en el error

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa, igual casi la mayoría de los post del enlace me dicen el mismo error al ejecutar

Comment: El enlace era para que revisas que soluciones le dieron a esas preguntas, revisaste que en algunas de ellas no recomiendan cierta libreria, en otra colocan un ejemplo descargando una libreria de nuget. No se si te leiste los comentarios y soluciones propuestas.

Comment: Si dices que lo que leiste es el mismo error, y hay preguntas resueltas, entonces quiere decir que puedes intentar con algunas de ellas. E incluso el codigo que utilizas se parece bastante a las otras preguntas.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa efectivamente dicen que usar y que no, al tratar de utilizar la que ellos recomienda me genera el mismo error que mencione especificando la linea

Comment: Tan rapido leiste y probaste todo, bueno como dice @MauricioAriasOlave, coloca la informacion de la excepcion completa. Si el `ex.ToString()` no da mas infomacion, entonce utiliza el `StackTrace` de la excepcion.

Comment: Es raro que al utlizar el `MensError = ex.ToString();` solo te devuelva un simple mensaje.

Comment: @JhonnyLuis el StackTrace dice: `Program.cs:línea 272`. ¿cuál es la línea 272 según tu código expuesto en la pregunta?. Yo revisaría si las credenciales son correctas. ¿De dónde obtienes los valores de `hostname` y `port`? - si es del web.config, es posible que esas claves no existan.

Comment: Revisate estas [indicaciones](https://afterlogic.com/docs/webmail-pro-net/troubleshooting/i-m-getting-can-t-connect-to-pop3-server-check-pop3-server-settings-how-to-resolve) adicional esa excepcion es como si falta alguna llave en algun archivo de configuracion, Lo que si te puedo asegurar es que los ejemplos de la red no uttilizan Pop3 si no que utilizan IMAP.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave la linea 272 es client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl); las variables mencionadas son declaradas al principio de la clase

Comment: Estas utilizando el host, el puerto y el ssl correcto para el smtp, tienes habilitado en pop3 en el servidor.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa Siii claro todo esta habilitado por parte de pop3 y IMAP, pero al tratar de utilizar los ejemplo mencionados en los post del enlace tantos para pop3 y imap generan el mismo error en la misma linea, y como mencione tengo un aplicativo echo en java que se conecta por pop3 y funciona bien

Comment: (-_-) rayos, ya trataste de abrir el visual studio como administrador, habilitar alguna regla en el firewall, el antivirus te estará bloqueando o sera algun bug en la libreria. Tremenda galleta con la que te has topado.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa, por defecto se tiene el visual studio que ejecute como administrador, antivirus el que trae el sistema, la reglas del firewall no se a que te refieres

Comment: usas estos datos para conectarte por pop3 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=es-419, importante el puerto, ademas si lees el link veras que esto hay que habilitarlo